# Format a number in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I have this as input

```
1234567890123
```

I want it to be displayed as

```
12 3456789012 3
```

Is this at all possible? My attempts so far were unsuccesful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the cells you want and go to `Format Cells > Number > Custom`. Inside the `Type` box, enter the following expression:

```
## ########## #
```

Click OK, and you're done.

If you want to know more about Excel's Custom Number Formatting, see the answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/201489/excel-custom-number-formatting).

Comment: Looks like I have a different issue. It works fine in a new workbook, but not in the existing one I try to use.

Comment: My issue was that the value was stored as text instead of a number. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad to help. You're welcome.