# Excel Format Cells Oddly Not Working

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, format

I want to format the number :

```
100007878
```

to be displayed like :

```
1 0000 7878
```

But when I put :

```
# #### ####
```

in Excel's formatting formula, I've got the following result :

```
100 007 878
```

I've searched this site, according to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/367468/format-a-number-in-excel), it should work. I find it odd.

How can I get the right display ?

Comment: It should work. Can you open new worksheet and try again? Basically, write your number, right click -> Format cells -> [Number] -> Custom and put # #### #### in Type. It works for me.

Comment: Works for me too... Do you have any other formula on the page which affects the layout/formatting? Although your question isn't clear - do you have the quote marks in your excel sheet? If not, please remove them, the formatting you've added here is enough without also needed ""